# Pythonic fast way for working with dict and array

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

I am working with really huge data size. I have a calculation in my code that take much much much time. the code is as below:

```
chester_output_connections = ['0', '5', '0', '1', '0', '2', '0', '3', '0', '4', '1', '9', '1', '2', '1', '6', '1', '8', '2', '9', '2', '3', '2', '8', '3', '9', '3', '7', '3', '8']

dic = {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 3, 5: 4, 6: 5, 7: 6, '2fit': 7}

for index,item in enumerate(chester_output_connections):
    for k,v in dic.items():
        if str(v)==str(item):
            chester_output_connections[index]=str(k)
```

Please make suggestions for better run time.

Comment: You can start by not looping over both. Create an inverse lookup for the dictionary, for example.

Comment: Once you have an inverse dictionary, you can simply use a list comprehension to update `chester_output_connections`.

Answer (score -1):

It *might* help if you don't convert the comparison to a string

```
if str(v)==str(item):
```

maybe (since item is already a string)

```
if str(v)==item:
```

might speed it up a tad.. ??